# Resque log handling: what sort of strategy?

Tags: logging, resque

I'm having some issues with the Resque logger. It all works well when i start it normally from the command line (it flushes to standard output). But as soon as I deamonize it, I don't see the log anymore. I thought it would default to the Rails app logger, but nothing shows up there. Plus, I'm using a library which writes most of its output (mostly for debugging purposes) to standard error and standard output (namely, $stderr and $stdout). Do these constants flush to the resque logger (moreover, should they)? How could I bundle them all together?

Not only that, I wanted to write the log of a forked process into a separate file, that is, I need to change the log file before I process the job. Where (which hook) is the best for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Question-1 :

I thought it would default to the Rails app logger

#### Answer 1:

Nope Resque logger default log to [`STDOUT`](https://github.com/resque/resque/blob/1-x-stable/lib/resque.rb#L474)  you have change it to log to specific file.

#### Question 2:

Plus, I'm using a library which writes most of its output (mostly for debugging purposes) to standard error and standard output (namely, $stderr and $stdout).

#### Answer 2:

Nope, unless they log there output with `Resque.logger.[info|warn|error]` syntax

#### Question 3:

Not only that, I wanted to write the log of a forked process into a separate file, that is, I need to change the log file before I process the job. Where (which hook) is the best for it?

#### Answer 3:

Well I think you can do that all you have to do is redefine the `Resque.logger` in resque hook 
   like `before_perform`

```
   def self.before_perform
     Resque.logger = File.open(File.join("path"))
   end
```

and then use `Resque.logger.[info | warn | error]` everywhere

Hope this help

Comment: I used the gem resque_logger and patched it to serve my needs, since it wasn't compatible with the resque_status gem extension. Nevertheless, what you wrote was mostly right, and I had to face similar issues concerning activerecord connections, which I had to solve with a variation of your response.